# Why is array[0] returning a different object than array.first using jQuery and why can't I use .val( )?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm selecting an array of input objects using jQuery and I'm running into an interesting problem when I try to chain together multiple methods after selecting one of the array elements. Can anyone explain to me why I get this behavior?

```
jQuery('.custom-size').first().find('input:hidden')
returns =>  

[<input id=​"custom_order_custom_sizes_attributes_0_size_id" name=​"custom_order[custom_sizes_attributes]​[0]​[size_id]​" type=​"hidden" value=​"138">​
, 
<input name=​"custom_order[custom_sizes_attributes]​[0]​[_destroy]​" type=​"hidden" value=​"0">​
]
```

If I select one of the elements using jQuery `.first()` or `.last()` and then call `.val()`, I get the expected value of `"138"`.

When I try to use a location in the array, I can return the element of the array:

```
var input = jQuery('.custom-size').first().find('input:hidden')[1]
returns => 
<input name=​"custom_order[custom_sizes_attributes]​[0]​[_destroy]​" type=​"hidden" value=​"0">
```

I can't call `.val()` on this object however. Instead I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val'
```

I can use `.slice(x,y)` to return the single element, but this seems rather silly. What am I missing here.

Comment: Put together a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem, that way we can play with it and maybe help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code:

```
$(".something")[0]
```

gets a single *DOM element* from the jQuery set. This code does the same as if you do

```
document.getElementsByClassName("something")[0]
```

Retrieved DOM element doesn't have `val()` method, since it is not a jQuery object.

In order to get the first *jQuery object* from jQuery set, you may use either [`:eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector (or [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method), or [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector (or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method):

```
$(".something:eq(0)");   // $(".something").eq(0);
$(".something:first");   // $(".something").first();
```

Comment: why does .slice(x,y) work here? I presume it return a jQuery object... but not sure why?

Comment: @Paul Because jQuery has wonderful [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method.

Comment: Oh didn't realize that was a jQuery method. Rubified JS :)

Answer (score 5):

If you access a jQuery object with bracket notation and index, it returns the raw DOM element at that index. DOM elements don't have any jQuery methods.

`.first`, `.last` or `.eq` on the other hand return a jQuery object. To get a jQuery object at a specific index `n`, use `$(...).eq(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

The native location by index (`[1]`) returns the specified DOM element.
jQuery functions like `.first()` return a jQuery object (pretty much DOM elements wrapped in a jQuery skin) that has those other functions.